# Convert Java Instant to .Net DateTime.Ticks

Tags: java, datetime

I need to convert an `Instant` into .Net's [`DateTime.Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks), i.e. a long that represents the number of one-hundred nanoseconds since 0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001.

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as a `ChronoUnit.HUNDRED_NANOS`, so it seems one has to roll ones own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `toDotNetDateTimeTicks(Instant)` below does the trick.

```
static long hundredNanosUntil(Instant begin, Instant end) {
    long secsDiff = Math.subtractExact(end.getEpochSecond(), begin.getEpochSecond());
    long totalHundredNanos = Math.multiplyExact(secsDiff, 10_000_000);
    return Math.addExact(totalHundredNanos, (end.getNano() - begin.getNano()) / 100);
}

static final Instant dotNetEpoch = ZonedDateTime.of(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                               ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();

static long toDotNetDateTimeTicks(Instant i) {
    return hundredNanosUntil(dotNetEpoch, i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Having in mind that 1 tick equals 100 ns and using the notation of [Eugene Beresovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709537/eugene-beresovsky) solution here is another solution using the `Duration` class, together with a conversion from .Net ticks to Instant.

```
static final Instant dotNetEpoch = ZonedDateTime.of(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();

// Converts Instant to .NET Tick
static long toDotNetDateTimeTicks(Instant i) {
    Duration d =Duration.between(dotNetEpoch, i);       
    long secTix =Math.multiplyExact(d.getSeconds(), 10_000_000) ;
    long nanoTix = d.getNano()/ 100 ;
    long tix = Math.addExact(secTix,nanoTix);
    return tix;
}


// Converts .NET Tick to Instant
static Instant toInstantFromDotNetDateTimeTicks(long dotNetTicks) {
    long millis =Math.floorDiv(dotNetTicks,10000) ;
    long restTicks = Math.floorMod(dotNetTicks,10000);
    long restNanos =restTicks*100;
    return dotNetEpoch.plusMillis(millis).plusNanos(restNanos);
}
```

Comment: thanks. but what is plusMillis and plusNanos? can you please explain them.

Comment: @Reza : check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#plusMillis-long-